# Помогите понять, как отрисовывать таблицы из JSON данных через Vue.js

Tags: javascript, html, css, json, vue.js

Написал REST приложение на Spring Boot, сейчас пробую писать для него фронтенд на Vue.js

Пример приходящих из контроллера данных:

```
[
  {
    "id": 11,
    "name": "Burger King",
    "address": "ул.Садовая 1",
    "meals": [
      {
        "id": 22,
        "name": "CheeseBurger set",
        "price": 400,
        "date": "2020-02-09"
      },
      {
        "id": 23,
        "name": "FishBurger set",
        "price": 500,
        "date": "2020-02-09"
      },
      {
        "id": 21,
        "name": "ChickenBurger set",
        "price": 300,
        "date": "2020-02-09"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

Как должен выглядеть скрипт, отрисующий это в виде таблицы на html странице?

Answer (score 0):

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    results: [{a:1,b:2},{a:3,b:4},{a:5,b:6}],
  },
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <div v-for="r in results">
    <span>a={{r.a}}</span>,
    <span>b={{r.b}}</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Еще больше примеров работы с Vue, можно найти на моем CodePen https://codepen.io/latdev/pens/public

Answer (score 0):

Вот [пример](https://codesandbox.io/s/github/vuejs/vuejs.org/tree/master/src/v2/examples/vue-20-grid-component?from-embed) использования Grid-компонента, который должен здесь отлично подойти.